# WPF Custom Popup Window causes program to crash?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a program that lives in the task bar (via a hidden Form), which generates a pop up window (a wpf window class custom built) that displays if the start up was completely successful or not. This program is set to run on start up (as the actual product will run) and when I start the computer up and the program launches, the program will stop responding. I am not sure if this is caused by the fact that it starts up opening a second window as well (the actual user interface) or if it is that the computer has too much happening at once. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: add some exception handling, or check event log, I believe that is because your code fail on popup open.

Comment: Did you try [logging](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to see what happens in your program?

Comment: I tried to add login and have the program spit out an error box when it runs however it just freezes and won't get to a state at which it will give returns.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience WPF apps can crash for various reasons that you wouldn't expect, so here's how to troubleshoot problems with WPF app startup.

First make sure that your app has proper exception handling: try/catch on every entry point and in your case - unhandled exception event listener attached in the first possible spot in the app:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,args)=>{
       MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Exception: "+args.ExceptionObject);
    };
```

Then make sure your app runs correctly when you execute it directly

WPF apps have a somewhat obscured startup, their Main() method is in a generated partial class obj\App.g.cs, the other part of this class is empty App.xaml.cs
If you're experiencing issues with deserializing the BAML you won't even see your MainWindow.xaml.cs code execute. What you'd need to do in that case is copy the contents of obj\App.g.cs into a new class Program.cs, make that the startup class for your app and put the error handler mentioned above as the first line in your copied Main() method in Program.cs:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("PresentationBuildTasks","4.0.0.0")]
public static void Main() {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s,args)=>{
       MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Exception: "+args.ExceptionObject);
    };
    Storm.Designer.App app = new Storm.Designer.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

Comment: And these startup popups are so annoying, if there isn't a good reason for it just don't do it.

Comment: (Answer) - The application that launches everything is just a standard windows form (so that we can do certain things with the notify icon).
(Comment) - The popups are as minimal as possible as we know that people don't want to be bothered (Drop Box is notorious, and we are trying to make sure we are definitely less bothersome than that).

Comment: You can use NotifyIcon from WPF app as well, you'll need to reference Windows.Forms and System.Drawing, then in your window constructor you can add code such as:
   NotifyIcon notify = new NotifyIcon(){
      BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info,
      Icon = new Icon(@"Storm.ico"),
      Visible = true,
};
notify.MouseClick += (s, arg) => {if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                        else
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;};

Comment: Perhaps then I should look into converting the app into a pure wpf application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your application depends on some service, that loaded after wpf app loaded??? 
You can start wpf app with a Task Scheduler, where you can set next usefull parameters:
At startup,
Delay task for x minutes,
restart app if it crashes,
etc.